# How to write an apology message to a professor when you've accidently been arrogant?

Tags: research-undergraduate, email, interpersonal-issues

I'm a first year and our professor was taking students for a research paper; we had to call the professor so he could ask us some questions. I was kind of nervous, and when he asked me if I'd done any hackathons or had any experience with the subject at hand, (related to comp sci), I said I'd "studied computer science at school for three years."

What I meant to say was I took comp sci in school and I just kind of panicked and it came out that way. And then he said "okay." And the topic shifted so I couldn't elaborate after that about experience.

He's really nice but he doesn't know me at all, and I feel like I came off as arrogant. He also said they might not be able to take students and I just feel like he may not like me that much because of that.

I want to write a message explaining how I didn't mean to say it like that and also telling more about my CS experience. Also that sounds like I have a lot of experience but really I don't have that much (just processing.js, python data structures, arduino, atmega, thats it).

How should I frame this message? I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Why do you think that sounds arrogant?

Comment: Which bit do you think seems arrogant? "I've studied comp sci in school for three years" and "I took scomp sci in school" both seem to have the same tone and the same basic message, I personally wouldn't even remember one phrasing over the other.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to send an email. Your reply was totally innocuous and a follow-up email would probably seem more inappropriate than what you said. The entirety of the feedback you got from the professor is “okay” - you are catastrophising (imagining the worst even against all reasonableness).

It sounds like you may be a bit anxious. This is really common among first year university students and, in my experience, more so if you have been a “good” student so far. See if your uni has pastoral support or mental health resources that could use. This particular incident is really nothing to worry about.

Comment: +1, though absent other evidence of anxiety, seeking psychological help might also be an overreaction. Things like this are more quickly forgotten as you gain experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any apology is necessary, but a note to the professor can be useful unless the class is huge. Say that you misunderstood the question about hackathons and might have given the impression that you know more than you really do. Thank the prof for providing the opportunity and express your interest. If you don't have explicit knowledge of the subject, do a bit of exploration of it first so that you have an idea whether any of your current knowledge might apply.

If you find relevant background in your own knowledge you could mention that briefly. But keep the mail short and fairly formal. Don't write to a prof as if they were one of your friends. Your writing here has the appropriate formality (i.e. no tweet-speak, etc)

For a class of hundreds, however, any mail might just be noise.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I frame this message?

**Concisely.** Sending a follow-up e-mail seems like a good idea; it shows interest and allows you to clarify your answer. But do not do engage in a post-mortem of what went wrong during the call; just write a short, professional e-mail in which you clarify one of your answers and reiterate your interest in the position. Your e-mail should be one paragraph, 2-4 sentences long. (In particular, I recommend a fairly abrupt sign-off; no need for the typical undergraduate "thank you for your time and please do not hesitate to reach out if there's anything...")